# placing class instances in a list during runtime

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.x

I am using Python3.

1. I created a class called Players() which contains 9 attributes. As an example, one of the attributes is Player.name
2. I then created 9 instances of the class named    p1,p1....p9.
3. During run time, the user is asked to pick the players and put them in a list called.....lineup.  This is the code I used:

   ```
     for i in range(0,9):
         name = input("Enter player....")     #user picks an instance of the Player class
         lineup.append(name)                    #this loops 9 times so all the instances are picked and placed in the lineup list
   ```

4.When I print the list on the screen, it appears as ['p2', 'p4',...........,'p1']   # or whatever order the user picked

5 If I try to call one of the instances from the list with its attribute, for example.....lineup[index].name, I get the error message that
  "str does not have an attribute called name"

6. However, if I define the list as lineup = [p1,p3,.....etc] before run time (in which case the user has no choice).....lineup[index].name
   works fine.
7. My question is....how do I allow the user to create the list so it looks like this....[p1,p2,p3....] instead of ['p1', 'p2',.....]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is generating `lineup` as a list of strings with values `"p1"`, `"p2"`... You need to somehow correspond each value they enter to one of your player variables. A simple (this is definitely not the best) way to do it would be to define a function:

```
def str_to_player(player_name):
    if player_name == "p1":
        return p1
    if player_name == "p2":
        return p2
    ....
```

Note that this function is fairly slow and `p1`, `p2`... all have to be in the scope of the function. See if you can find a better way to correspond strings to player names!

Comment: Thanks. Found this helpul, especially in conjunction with other responses

Answer (score 0):

You want to create instances of your `Player` class using the input you receive and add those to your list. For example

```
# Simple Player class
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Player: ' + self._name

# Prompt for player names and return a list of Player instances
def get_players():
    lineup = []
    for _ in range(9):
        name = input("Enter player ... ")
        player = Player(name)
        lineup.append(player)
    return lineup

def main():
    lineup = get_players()

    print(lineup)
    print("Your Player lineup is")
    for i, p in enumerate(lineup, 1):
        print('{0}. {1}'.format(i, p.get_name()))

    # Example: Prompt for position and output Player name at position
    while True:
        pos = input("Get player at position: ")
        if not pos: # enter empty line to quit
            break

        # get a Player instance from lineup list at index
        player_at = lineup[int(pos) - 1]
        print("Player at position {0} is {1}".format(pos, player_at.get_name()))
```

---

**Edit:**

I may have misunderstood how the user was entering a name, thinking it was any name `'Bob'` instead of some key (`'p1', 'p2', ...`) so instead you can create a dictionary to map the key to your Player instance.

```
player_map = {
    'p1': Player('player 1'),
    'p2': Player('player 2'),
    'p3': Player('player 3'),
    'p4': Player('player 4'),
    'p5': Player('player 5'),
    'p6': Player('player 6'),
    'p7': Player('player 7'),
    'p8': Player('player 8'),
    'p9': Player('player 9')
}
```

And then you can get each player instance.

Note: no handling has been added for human error. Eg invalid key.

```
def get_players():
    lineup = []
    for _ in range(len(player_map)):
        name = input("Enter player ... ")
        lineup.append(player_map[name])
    return lineup
```

Answer (score 0):

The core issue you're encountering is that a string like `"p1"` isn't the same thing as a variable named `p1`. There are several ways you can work around this issue to do what you want.

The "easiest" way might be to use `eval` to lookup the variable based on the string provided by the user. This *will* work, but it's a very bad idea, since the user could type in any valid Python expression, which will be run in your program. That means they could type in code that would delete the hard drive, or send spam email, or do whatever else they can think of. Certainly don't do this if you don't trust all of the users of your program (e.g. if it's accessible over the internet)!

Another approach would be to create the instances of your class only when they are named by the user. If you don't actually need to set the player instances up ahead of time, this might be a very easy solution. Just pass the user's string as a parameter to your class's `__init__` method as you create each instance.

A third approach, and probably the best, is to use a dictionary to map from names to instances, rather than using a bunch of variables. Variable names are intended for use by the programmer. They're generally not data that should be exposed to the user of a program. If you need to associate a name to an object, use a data structure that can map between them. A dictionary is a natural choice, since it maps between hashable keys (such as strings) and arbitrary objects (such as your instances).

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful